# Tensorflow JS model gives different results from Tensorflow python when trained on the same data

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow python model using Keras that works well which I'd like to replicate and use in the browser for both training and predictions completely in the browser. Here's the python model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(199,)),  
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(0.25),  
  layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

When I export the model and import it into tfjs using `tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, tfjs_export_file_name)` it works fine in the browser - the same input data generates the same results.

However when I create a new tfjs model with the same topology as in python and train it *in the browser* on the same data I get very different results.

```
    const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [
        tf.layers.batchNormalization({inputShape:[199]}),
        tf.layers.dense({units: 128, inputShape:[199],useBias:true,activation: 'relu'}),
        tf.layers.dropout({rate:0.25}),
        tf.layers.dense({units: 8, activation: 'sigmoid'}),
        ]
    });
```

Training, label, and input data have been triple-checked. They are the same.

My goal is to create and train a model in tfjs that matches the Python output.

A simplified version that recreates the problem is here: https://github.com/blairwheadon/tftest/tree/master

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Do you set and fix the random seed for tensorflow?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks for the suggestion I'll look into that.

Comment: Support for non-default seeds appears to be non-existent in tfjs 2.1. I couldn't find a way to set the global seed in the API docs, and when I attempted to set an operations specific seed on my dropout layer I got 'Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Non-default seed is not implemented in Dropout layer yet: 10946'

Comment: Interesting, maybe submit a feature request ro tensorflow?